# How to conditionally enable onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a table by mapping my data , I'm trying to create a `TableSortLable` , but I only want to enable the users to sort by the first two columns .

```
          {
            Columns.map(c,index => {
              return (
                <TableCell key={c.key} component="th" padding="checkbox">
                  <TableSortLabel 
                     active={props.brokersListOrderByColumn === c.key}
                     direction={props.brokersListSortOrder}
                     onClick={() => props.setOrderBy(c.key)}>
                     {c.label}
                  </TableSortLabel>
                </TableCell>
              )
            })
          }
```

I was thinking on using the `onClick` event, and to enable it only when its the first or second column . I tried something like:

```
   {(index === 1 || index ===2) && onClick={() => props.setOrderBy(c.key)}}>
```

Or conditionally setting the `onClick` value , but both didn't work .

I've also tried conditionally setting the `TableSortOrder` :

```
                <TableCell key={c.key} component="th" padding="checkbox">
                  {(index === 1 || index === 2) && <TableSortLabel 
                     active={props.brokersListOrderByColumn === c.key}
                     direction={props.brokersListSortOrder}
                     onClick={() => props.setOrderBy(c.key)}>
                     {c.label}
                  </TableSortLabel>}
                  {(index !== 1 && index !== 2) && c.label}
                </TableCell>
```

But it complains `c` is undefined

Comment: Is `TableSortLable` a typo? (on line 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error. You should write **parameters in brackets** for functors. Like this

```
Columns.map((c, index) => {...
```

Otherwise engine will try to find (RHS) variable *c* (expected as function).
You didnt init such variable and get this

> But it complains c is undefined .

Answer (score 1):

Try to give something like

```
onClick={
    () => (index === 1 || index === 2) && props.setOrderBy(c.key)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `onClick={(index === 1 || index === 2) ? () => props.setOrderBy(c.key) : null}`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just add check inside handler?

```
onClick={() => {
   if((index === 1 || index ===2)) {
       props.setOrderBy(c.key)}
   } 
}}
```

You can also extract array function for breivity:

```
const onClick = () => {
   if((index === 1 || index ===2)) {
       props.setOrderBy(c.key)}
   } 
}
```

....

```
onClick={onClick}>
```

Comment: Pretty sure `index` isn't defined in the JavaScript context.